# VB Map Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, dictionary, asp-classic, vbscript

I am relatively new to ASP and VBScript, and I have a program that I'm working on that would be much easier with a map. However, after doing some searching, I can't find anything about a map in VB.

**Is there a way to have something like the C++ `map <Key, Value>` in VBScript?**

I would prefer to avoid downloading external resources. If not, whats the best alternative? Right now I just have a very large `Select` statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name for **Map** in VBScript is **Dictionary**. Then docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

*Sample code:*

Select approach :

```
>> a = Array(1, 2, 3)
>> For Each e In a
>>     Select Case e
>>       Case 1
>>         e = "alpha"
>>       Case 2
>>         e = "beta"
>>       Case 3
>>         e = "gammay"
>>     End Select
>>     WScript.Echo e
>> Next
>>
alpha
beta
gammay
```

Dictionary approach :

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d(1) = "alpha"
>> d(2) = "beta"
>> d(3) = "gamma"
>> For Each e In d
>>     WScript.Echo d(e)
>> Next
>>
alpha
beta
gamma
```

As you can see, the key type of a VBScript Dictionary is not restricted to `String`; numbers, dates, ..., and even objects work just as well. Another difference: the order of the key-value-pairs in a Dictionary is stable and reflects the order of entry.

Comment: Ah, that would exlpain why searching for map got me nowhere. Thank you